# Perfect vacuum in experiment

Tags: experimental-physics, speed-of-light, pressure, vacuum

When conducting experiments to determine the speed of light in a perfect vacuum does that vacuum(?) replicate outer space?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking? Are you asking how experimental pressures compare with pressures in outer space?

Comment: John, you summed it up for me exactly.  Does the experiment measuring the speed of light in the lab represent outer space?

Comment: Who says outer space is a vacuum?

Answer (score 1):

No.

Even a really strong vacuum tube cannot suck out all the air in the tube, but it is very near the real speed of light in vacuum.

In most experiments, that is enough, but when you are talking about the speed of light, this little air in the tube can influence the accuracy of the speed calculated.

Comment: Then again, outer space isn't perfectly empty. Intergalactic space can have densities less than 1 atom/cc. Interstellar space can have densities on the order of 1 million atoms/cc.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast: Interstellar space can have densities on the order of [1 atom/cc as well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstellar_medium).